# Integration Error

Tags: algebra-precalculus

So I just learned integration, and a problem said to find $\int\frac{x^3+6x^2-7x+9}{2x^2+6x-9}dx$.

My steps are as follows:

[image: integration steps]

I know I made some mistakes somewhere, because differentiating doesn't yield the initial function.

Comment: Ugh, I hate this big rational functions.

Comment: Somewhere your $-\frac 92$ in the denominator became $+\frac 92$

Comment: are there any other significant errors?

Comment: When you fix that, it will change the numbers in the numerator of that last therm  and the it will give you the choice of partial fractions of an secant substitution.  I think partial fractions are a little easier.

Comment: Your computations are very difficult to follow. You should at least use arrows to indicate their order.

Comment: @JeanMarie  they go down one column then into another

Comment: The final answer will be $\frac 14 x^2 + \frac 32 x + A \ln(2x + 3 + \sqrt 3) + B \ln (2x + 3 - \sqrt 3)$  You still have to solve for $A$ and $B$ though.

Comment: Yup! I got an answer of that form, and it differentiated correctly. Thank you